Is it possible to test an FFmpeg command without actually running it?
I'm generating complex and long FFmpeg scripts, which I want to be able to test. Since I am only testing the script I don't want to lose time on running script.
How can I validate the FFmpeg script without actually running it?
I know that I can use -t 1 property to cut the video and I also can use very low quality video for testing. I would like to find an even faster solution.

Simply run the scripts on prepared small files, assuming they don't need lengthy or high quality videos. If they do, there's nothing you can do about it, no way to be faster. Even if you simulated it without videos somehow, which is basically science-fiction, the same algorithms would still be ran by ffmpeg, with the same computional power and time required.
Another option to make things faster is to run multiple commands in many terminal tabs. If your CPU/GPU can't handle it, upgrade your machine or do it on a server.

You have to run the command, since some issues are only uncovered when filters see the media data they'll be working with.
